# in Windows, Junctioning a Folder and then Symbiotic Link why is not working?

Tags: windows, symlink, junction

I am trying to make this work:

I created a Junction folder (using the mklink /J command) to a Z: Drive pointing to FolderA on a C: drive. Then I created several HardLinks (mklink /H command) inside another C:drive folder (We're calling name folderB), This files inside B are hardlink files to FolderA files...

I know connect via Network to the Z: Drive and update files inside FolderA junction ... When I directly open the files inside FolderA on drive C they are update. But when I go to check the other Hardlinks in FolderB they are not updated...

Why is it not working?

Comment: Ask this on Super User, and please include the exact commands you use to create the junction mountpoint and hard links, and precisely describe what the Z: drive is in all contexts.

Comment: FYI, we can't resolve a junction mountpoint to a remote device. A mountpoint on a remote volume that targets drive C: will access the remote C: drive, not the caller's local C: drive (i.e. the reparse is handled on the server side). OTOH, a symbolic link on a remote volume that targets drive C: will access the caller's local C: drive, not the remote C: drive (i.e. the reparse is handled on the client side).

Comment: Also you appear to be confusing symbolic links (a type of reparse point) with hardlinks (another reference to a file within a filesystem). The title mentions "symbiotic" [sic] links and you tagged this "symlink", but your example creates no symlinks.